# Finding the location in google maps

Tags: google-maps

We have been using google maps api , but have a clarification. Is there any method which allows the user to know the nearest city as in when the user moves the mouse over the map .

Like the user hovers over the map from one country to another country, so is there any way to display the city name outside the map through an event.

I am aware that it is possible to get the user's current location through geolocation propertY, but is it possible to get the requirement described above ?

Comment: Reverse geocode the location of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know I can use reverse geocoding to obtain the designation of a place where you are based on its coordinates. At this point the problem is to define what you mean by the nearest town, you mean the center of the city where you are or drawn a town bordering the town where you are. In the first case using the name of the city you've got you can find with normal geocoding coordinates of the center of this city, in the latter case you have to develop a specific strategy.